# forbid+O+to+V.......to-infinitive

Tags: grammar

I forbade him to enter my office.

If 'to enter my office' is an object complement, then why is it 'to enter my office' in stead of 'not to enter my office'? If it's an object complement, shouldn't it be describing the object's future? So, therefore I think it's a direct object. Am I right?

Comment: 'to enter my office' modifies "forbade".  It's not an object complement.

Comment: It is an object complement, but _forbid_ is a negative verb. You don't want to add an extra negative.